# what should be my int x,y in my cropping detect face?

Tags: android

Hello Android Programmers here, kindly check my code to fill the parameters about cropping the image detected.

I don't know what should be the values to put in parameters about cropping the face detected in android using `createBitmap(Bitmapsource,x,y,width,height).`
How can i get some integer for the x and y to fill the parameters in Bitmap function.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {

        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();

        if (mAbsoluteFaceSize == 0) {
            int height = mGray.rows();
            if (Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize) > 0) {
                mAbsoluteFaceSize = Math.round(height * mRelativeFaceSize);
            }
            mNativeDetector.setMinFaceSize(mAbsoluteFaceSize);
        }

        MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();

        if (mDetectorType == JAVA_DETECTOR) {
            if (mJavaDetector != null)
                mJavaDetector.detectMultiScale(mGray, faces, 1.1, 2, 2, // TODO: objdetect.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
                        new Size(mAbsoluteFaceSize, mAbsoluteFaceSize), new Size());
        }
        else if (mDetectorType == NATIVE_DETECTOR) {
            if (mNativeDetector != null)
                mNativeDetector.detect(mGray, faces);
        }
        else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Detection method is not selected!");
        }

        Rect[] facesArray = faces.toArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < facesArray.length; i++) 
            Core.rectangle(mRgba, facesArray[i].tl(), facesArray[i].br(), FACE_RECT_COLOR, 3);

        //crop

        //crop
        viewWidth = part1.getMeasuredWidth();
        viewHeight = part1.getMeasuredHeight();
        //create the bitmap
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mRgba.cols(), mRgba.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); 
        Resizebmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, x, y, viewWidth, viewHeight);


        try {
            Utils.matToBitmap(mRgba, bmp);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Utils.matToBitmap() throws an exception: " + e.getMessage());
            bmp.recycle();
            bmp = null;
        }


        return mRgba;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong. Do you mean that you had detected the face in a large bitmap and you want to crop the face out to a smaller bitmap? 
For example, you have a 640 x 480 bitmap and you found the face inside rectangular with upper left x1, y1 and lower right x2, y2. Then it should be something like:

```
resizeBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
```

Comment: how can i get my x and y value ? thru the rectangular of the face